# Как привести массив byte[] к виду CharSequence?

Tags: java, массивы, char, byte

Нужно написать класс `AsciiCharSequence`, который реализует хранение последовательности ASCII-символов в массиве байт. По сравнению с классом `String`, хранящим каждый символ как char, `AsciiCharSequence` будет занимать меньше памяти.

Класс `AsciiCharSequence` должен:

- реализовывать интерфейс `java.lang.CharSequence`;
- иметь конструктор, принимающий массив байт;
- определять методы `length()`, `charAt()`, `subSequence()` и `toString()`

Ну вот я почти написал:

```
public class AsciiCharSequence implements CharSequence {

     byte[] a1;

  public AsciiCharSequence(byte[] a){  //Конструктор класса
        a = this.a1;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {    //Переопределение toString()
        return "AsciiCharSequence{" +
                "a1=" + Arrays.toString(a1) +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public int length(){
        return a1.length;
    }; //Переопределение length()

    @Override
    public char charAt(int index){      //Переопределение charAt()
        char t000 = (char)a1[index];
        return t000;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end){  //Переопределение subSequence()
        CharSequence buf[] = new CharSequence[end - start];

       for(int i=start; i<=end;i++)
       {
           byte t = a1[i-start];
          buf[i]=(CharSequence)t;
       }
         return buf[end -start];
    }
}
```

Самый проблемный участок = Переопределение `subSequence()`. Это последние 12 строчек с конца. Проблема такая: я никак не могу написать код, чтобы метод возвращал корректный тип (`CharSequence`?). Если алгоритм формирования массива более-менее понятен, то преобразование массива `byte[]` в `CharSequence` совсем не ясен. Сам метод должен применяться на массив символов и возвращать массив символов с индексами лежащими от `start` до `end`. К примеру,

```
String s0 = "Вова и Дима козлы";
   s0.subSequence(14,16)
```

Должен возвращать "злы".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно переписать класс в таком виде:

```
public class AsciiCharSequence implements CharSequence {
    private byte[] data;

    public AsciiCharSequence(byte[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int length() {
        return data.length;
    }

    @Override
    public char charAt(int index) {
        return (char) (data[index] & 0xff);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
        int length = end - start;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
        for (int i = 0, j = start; i < length; i++, j++) {
            bytes[i] = data[j];
        }
        return new AsciiCharSequence(bytes);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new String(data);
    }
}
```

Дернуто с гитхаба.
Автор - [Михаил Валейко](https://github.com/valeyko).

Comment: Ну таки `Arrays.copyOfRange` побыстрее будет. Плюс можно проверить, если `start == 0 && end == data.length`, возвращать просто this.

Answer (score 8):

Просто создайте новый экземпляр своего типа:

```
@Override
public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end){  //Переопределение subSequence()
    return new AsciiCharSequence(Arrays.copyOfRange(a1, start, end));
}
```

Заметьте, что `toString()` вы переопределили неправильно. В документации [ясно сказано](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#toString%28%29):

> `String toString()`
>
> Returns a string containing the characters in this sequence in the same order as this sequence. The length of the string will be the length of this sequence.

То есть если вы переопределяете интерфейс `CharSequence`, вы обязаны вернуть в `toString()` строку, которая соответствует содержимому вашего `CharSequence`. Сделать это несложно:

```
@Override
public String toString() {    //Переопределение toString()
    return new String(a1, java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
}
```

Comment: Очень интересно. Похоже вы правы. Сейчас проверю.

Comment: Компилятор "степика" говорит, что у меня и length переопределен неверно.

Comment: Ваша версия subsequence у меня выбрасывает NullPointerException. Ну всё равно спасибо. Хотя бы теперь есть больше возможностей для устранения ошибок.

Comment: Вероятно, у вас `a1 == null`.

Comment: Ну правильно, посмотрите чего он в конструкторе делает :) `a = this.a1`...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ой, и верно.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov да вы глаз -алмаз.

Answer (score 2):

```
class AsciiCharSequence implements CharSequence {
    private byte[] byteSequence;

    public AsciiCharSequence(byte[] bytesSequence) {
        this.byteSequence = bytesSequence;
    }

    @Override
    public int length() {
        return byteSequence.length;
    }

    @Override
    public char charAt(int index) {
        return (char) byteSequence[index];
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
        return new AsciiCharSequence(java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(byteSequence, start, end));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new String(byteSequence);
    }
}
```